# What's the equivalent of React Native { flex: 1 } for React JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have been programming a lot in React Native and I'm trying React js (only web) and I don't know to make a simple View that get all screen to start play with all components.

Let me explain:

In React Native I handle the View dimensions with flex, something like this:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 0.5, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
      <Text>I'm a blue 50% screen View!</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 0.5, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
      <Text>I'm a yellow 50% screen View!</Text>        
    </View>
</View>
```

But in React JS I have to use div tags that doesn't recognize flex.
I mean, I cannot do this:

```
<div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <div style={{ flex: 0.5, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
      <p>I'm a blue 50% screen View!</p>
    </div>
    <div style={{ flex: 0.5, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
      <p>I'm a yellow 50% screen View!</p>        
    </div>
</div>
```

How I have to use that styles in React js for the divs to get the percentages results?

Comment: What do you mean, " I have to use div tags that doesn't recognize flex." ?

Comment: I mean that I make a div with style flex 1 and nothing happens instead of if I would do in react native

Comment: You can still use `div { flex: 1 }` in your css. It's a shorthand for `flex-grow: 1;flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0%; }`

Comment: I do and nothing happens, the div doesn't fills the whole screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React Native uses its own flexbox implementation - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox

In React you are using CSS flexbox - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flexbox

> Flexbox works the same way in React Native as it does in CSS on the web, with a few exceptions. The defaults are different, with flexDirection defaulting to column instead of row, and the flex parameter only supporting a single number.

In css, you also need to declare parent container as

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

and that is probably what you are missing.

pure CSS version of your flex would probably look like this (styles as "string" version):

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100vh;">
    <div style="flex: 1; background-color: blue;">
      <p>I'm a blue 50% screen View!</p>
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 1; background-color: yellow;">
      <p>I'm a yellow 50% screen View!</p>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding display: flex; make that flexDirection works but cannot set my div get all screen like it would make setting flex: 1 in react native

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJXrLd is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, something like, but it doesn't work. If I create a div with flex: 1, the other 2 div inside that have 1 . flex :0.2 and the other one flex :0.8 should mean that fist one is 20 % of the parent div and the other the 80% but it doesn't work.

And If you are the parent div, if that div have flex: 1 it should fills the whole screen

Comment: You need to give 100% height for `body` and `html`elements too. Also parent needs to have 100% height

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai its 0.2 of total flex value (0.2 + 0.8 = 1) => 0.2/1 = > 20% of **parent** div's height - so if you want to fullscreen it - your **parent** div needs to be 100% height of window